# Inconsistent null value reference exceptions

Tags: c#, asp.net, nullreferenceexception

I am facing inconsistent  null value reference errors while I am trying to store my values from a serialized class object.

```
if ( item.current_location.city!=null )
{
    var city = item.current_location.city.Select(i => i.ToString());
}
```

In the above code snippet, successful insertion takes place even if any index in `item` array has null values. But it throws exception in some cases,which I don't think can be distinguished in any manner from other cases( when the value is null)

Comment: What is the datatype of `city`? Collection of custom types?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`item` could be null as well

`current_location` could be null as well,

not only `city`.

This would help

```
if (item != null && 
    item.current_location != null && 
    item.current_location.city != null) {
    ...
}
```

EDIT:

Note: This code works, since c# implements a so-called shortcut-evaluation of Boolean expressions. If `item` should be `null`, the rest of the expression would not be evaluated. If  `item.current_location` should be `null`, the last term would not be evaluated.

---

(I do not see any insertion in the code above.)

---

Starting with C#6.0 you can use the null propagation operator (?):

```
var city = item?.current_location?.city?.Select(i => i.ToString());
if (city != null) {
     // use city ...
}
```

Comment: insert code didn't have any problem. I just mentioned what I m trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I can't give a definitive answer without seeing your dataset, but you're not checking for null values on the item object or the current_location object.  I would suggest you start by changing your test to this:

```
if (null != item && null != item.current_location && null != item.current_location.city)
{
...
}
```

Comment: I can not do that Matt, because in the current location I have other values like state and country,if a user hasn't specified one credential then according to your code other credentials will also be discarded.

Comment: Your code is correct; however, why are you beginning the checks with `null !=`. It looks like you were testing how much `null` is. `null` is always `null`. It seems more intuitive to look how much the values are, as they can change, `value != something`.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes : http://www.mathwords.com/s/symmetric_property.htm

It's personal preference, kinda like whether or not you're the type to copy someone's answer and then criticize it.

Comment: @Matt: Sorry, I did not want to offend you in any way. Only, in English, you would say, "If my variable is not null then ..." and not, "If null is not my variable then ..."